# How to capture user input multiple times in a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Could you help me with this little problem?
I'm trying to make a menu system which shows the options in a JEditorPane, it's something like this:

#### ***Welcome***

Select an option.
1.) New register.
2.) New input.
3.) Exit.

the options are chosen by the user through a JTextField, when "1" is entered it shows another menu:

#### New register

1.) Option X.
2.) Option Y.
3.) Back.

and so on, the problem is that I don't know how I can capture the user's input, advance to the next menu, and re-capture the user's input all in a JTextField.

```
textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String cap = "";

            cap = textField.getText();

            switch(cap) {

            case "1":
                paintEditorPane("Welcome");

                    // here is my problem, I don't know how to re-capture JTextField input
                 switch(cap){

                 case "1":
                       paintEditorPane("NewRegister");
                       break;
                    }
            break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you please show what you have done so far?

Comment: @suppko ok edited :)

Comment: 1) Why does you first sentence say you are using a JEditorPane and the rest of the question a JTextField. Be explicit with your question. 2) How is this question different than your last question: https://www.howtogeek.com/196087/how-to-add-websites-to-the-home-screen-on-any-smartphone-or-tablet/? 3) Why are you still using a JTextField for this? It is not the correct component as was suggested in your last question. I would also add you could use a `JComboBox`. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Combo Boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

Comment: @camickr At the beginning I explained that I used a JEditorPane, just to show, but not to enter text, and I do it with JTextField because I want to learn to use it, and not to use what they tell me on the internet;)

Comment: (1-) *I do it with JTextField because I want to learn to use it* - so learn to use the appropriate component for the job. A JtextField is NOT the appropriate component. *and not to use what they tell me on the internet* - we give advice on the proper way to use the components of the language. Companies like Apple an Microsoft spend millions of dollars designing usable interfaces that all uses will be able to understand and use in every application which keeps the learning curve short.  Learn by example, not your own approach.

Comment: I think I didn't understand. Whatever you say friend, after all I'm learning and apparently there are many geniuses here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's Basic. Now you have to make many cases to judge states.

```
public static class MainPanel extends JPanel{
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public MainPanel() {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.textArea = new JTextArea();// you can use constructor to set Text but I like use method "setText".
        this.textArea.addKeyListener(new keyHandler());
        this.textArea.setText("Welcome\r\nSelect an option. 1.) New register. 2.) New input. 3.) Exit.\r\n");
        this.textArea.setCaretPosition(this.textArea.getText().length());// move caret to last
        this.add(this.textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void addText(String text) {textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "\r\n" + text +"\r\n");}

    public class keyHandler extends KeyAdapter{
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            switch(e.getKeyCode()){
            case KeyEvent.VK_1 : addText("New register"); break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_2 : addText("New input"); break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_3 : addText("Exit"); break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your help, you don't know how much I've looked for someone to help me hahaha <3